# how to avoid to running program twice

Tags: c, linux

I wondering if there is a way to prevent user to launch many time the program to avoid some problems.

when start my program with

> /etc/init.d/myprog start

Next time when the user execute the same command it will not run.

Comment: Make a pid file and check whether the pid is running

Comment: If you mean run exactly once, then the program could delete itself. If you mean one instance then look at the process identifiers.

Comment: Normally, you would create a lock file where you store the process id of the program. On stop, you could kill the program with the specified id and remove the lock file. If a lock file is present, don't start the program again (or check if it is running)

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by running the program once. Do you mean there can't be multiple concurrent instances of the program, or do you want to forbid re-starting it if it terminates?

Comment: You could probably get the user in a headlock until the program ends.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is for the launcher to attempt a launch, capturing the pid of the launch into /var/run

Then on subsequent launches, you read the pid file, and do a process listing (ps) to see if a process with that pid is running.  If so, the subsequent launch will report that the process is already running and do nothing.

[Read up on pid and lock files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/what-are-pid-and-lock-files-for) to get an idea of what is considered standard under the init.d system.

Comment: My recommendation is that you also look at other process init.d scripts and leverage the pid and lock file patterns used there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) a .lock file and lock it with [flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html).

```
int fd = open("path/to/file.lock", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) { 
  /* error opening file, abort */ 
}
if (flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) == -1) { 
  /* other process already open, abort */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Linux Standard Base supports a [`start_daemon`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_2.0.1/LSB-generic/LSB-generic/iniscrptfunc.html) function that delivers this feature.  Use it from your init script.

> The start_daemon, killproc and pidofproc functions shall use this algorithm for determining the status and the pid(s) of the specified program. They shall read the pidfile specified or otherwise /var/run/basename.pid and use the pid(s) herein when determining whether a program is running. The method used to determine the status is implementation defined, but should allow for non-binary programs. [1](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_2.0.1/LSB-generic/LSB-generic/iniscrptfunc.html) Compliant implementations may use other mechanisms besides those based on pidfiles, unless the -p pidfile option has been used. Compliant applications should not rely on such mechanisms and should always use a pidfile. When a program is stopped, it should delete its pidfile. Multiple pid(s) shall be separated by a single space in the pidfile and in the output of pidofproc.
>
> This runs the specified program as a daemon. start_daemon shall check if the program is already running using the algorithm given above. If so, it shall not start another copy of the daemon unless the -f option is given. The -n option specifies a nice level. See nice(1). start_daemon should return the LSB defined exit status codes. It shall return 0 if the program has been successfully started or is running and not 0 otherwise.